# How To Create New Sobject In Dynamic Apex Class If Doesn't Exist In Org

Tags: apex, dynamic-apex

Salesforce documentation has [Dynamic Sobject Creation Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_dml.htm) The test class gives an example of how to check if object exists and the create the object. Unfortunately they use Account which every org has. How do you do the same thing with CustomObject__c c? Not Sobject s which I know we can use but requires get and put which is bit more cumbersome vs c.Name.

If I use `CustomObject__c = (CustomObject__c)DynamicSobjectCreation.createObject(typeName)` and it doesn't exist in the org, get a deployment error in SFDX.

> Invalid type: CustomObject__c

The point of the exercise is to see if the object exists in the first place and instantiate it.

```
    // Create a new sObject by passing the sObject type as an argument.
    **Account a = (Account)DynamicSObjectCreation.createObject(typeName);**        
    System.assertEquals(typeName, String.valueOf(a.getSobjectType()));
    // Set the account name and insert the account.
    a.Name = acctName;
    insert a;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE 2:**

You can't create an SObject in Apex if it doesn't exist in the system, because Salesforce doesn't know what fields etc. you want.

If you want to check if object exists in the org you can do the following

```
public static Boolean isSObjectExists(String sobjectName) {
    return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().containsKey(sobjectName);
}
```

just use GlobalSchema.

If you are not sure about SObject itself and want to work with it then use the following.

```
String sobjectName;
SObject obj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sobjectName).newSObject();

// obj.get('field');
// obj.put('field', 'value');
// obj.getSObjectType() == Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sobjectName).getDescribe().getSObjectType()
```

**UPDATE:**

here is the better performance option as per Adrian suggestion using `Type`.

```
public static Boolean isSObjectExists(String sobjectName) {
    return Type.forName('Schema', sobjectName) != null;
}
```

also dynamic creation

```
String sobjectName = 'Account';
SObject obj = (SObject) Type.forName('Schema', sobjectName).newInstance();

// obj.get('field');
// obj.put('field', 'value');
// obj.getSObjectType() == Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sobjectName).getDescribe().getSObjectType()
```

Comment: This approach is *significantly* slower than just `Type.forName(sObjectName) != null`.

Comment: true, thanks. To be honest didn't know Type.forName was working on SObject

Comment: I'll add a second option as per your suggestion

Comment: There's some minute chance of false positive with standard objects that have name shadowing such as `Location`, but I would still prefer it.

Comment: You can also create classes with names like `Account`, then probably better to use `Schema.Account`

Comment: I recommend switching the order, since global describe is really expensive to call.

Comment: Unfortunately this missed the question. The question is about instantiating the Sobject when it didn't exist. So AFTER checking it how to do equivalent of Account a = (Account)DynamicSObjectCreation.createObject(typeName) but with a custom object. CustomObject__c c = (CustomObject__c)DynamicSObjectCreation.createObject(typeName) throws an error the object does not exist.

Comment: I know we can use generic Sobject like listed but my question has to do with using the actual object name since we can use field references and is what is outlined in Salesforce Documentation

Comment: If that type does not exist, you cannot construct it. What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: It should be `Type.forName('Schema',sobjectName)`. This avoids any potential shadowing.

Comment: re: what was I hoping to achieve - Similar to SF Docs as listed in question the example is Account a = (results from SobjectCheck). If SobjectCheck fails it throws an error fine. But DX compiler checks if the Sobject exists in the org in this case before uploading. So if instead of Account I change the SF example to: SobjectDoesntExist__c a = (results from SobjectCheck) I cannot even upload that to an org b/c compiler error "Object doesn't exist". So I don't understand the example.

Comment: I know I can do with a generic Sobject and get/put statements but that seems like a less desirable option unless only one.